# Converting UTF-8/Unicode values to

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Can someone provide me a working code example that will properly parse a textfile string of Unicode values (like `&#x000A;&#x000D;`) and convert them into UTF-8 characters in PHP 5.4?

Previously, I used `html_entities_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, UTF-8)`.  But after 5.4, it is now not working.  Do I need to add something else to the `ENT_NOQUOTES` (like `ENT_COMPAT`?) or swap one for the other or is this totally barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs for `html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) (not `entities`, btw), the only significant change in 5.4 is that `UTF-8` is the default encoding.

However, the encoding should be in double-quotes, which you didn't do. That might or might not be the source of your problem.

I would try `html_entity_decode($string)` or `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_HTML5)` in PHP 5.4.